# How to capture 'confirm saveas' user input?

Tags: vim, buffer, overwrite, savefiledialog

I use this command to rename the current file and delete the file with the old name:
`:exe "confirm sav ".variable`

`Variable` is given in un inputdialog().

How can I capture the `confirm saveas` user input (overwrite yes or no) in order to do this:
if userinput == 'no' --> do nothing
if userinput == 'yes' --> delete old file and buffer: `call delete(expand('#')) | bd#`

Hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access the result of `:confirm`, but the effect of the `:saveas` can be observed: If the buffer isn't `'modified'` any more, the saving was done. To handle unmodified original buffers, the original state must be saved and restored.

```
let save_modified = &l:modified
setlocal modified
exe "confirm sav ".variable
if !&l:modified
    " User confirmed.
    call delete(expand('#')) | bd#
else
    " User canceled; restore original state.
    let &l:modified = save_modified
endif
```

Note: There's a plugin for renaming: [rename plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4840)

Answer (score 0):

the `confirm()` function is what you are looking for.

`:h confirm()` to check detailed argument description and examples.